# Цикл по коллекции

Tags: циклы, java

Допустим, у меня есть цикл типа

```
for (String s : getValues()) {
  ...
}
```

`getValues()` вызывается каждый раз или только перед началом цикла?

Answer (score 5):

Перед началом.

```
for (T element : collection) {
    // ...
}
//Эквивалентен
for (Iterator<T> i = collection.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
    T element = i.next();
    // ...
}
```